# Blank(White) Screen on Tizen TV after launched from renative

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tizen, tizen-web-app, renative

I'm trying to run a renative app on real Samsung Tizen TV and I've followed all the necessary steps mentioned in [this](https://renative.org/docs/platforms/tizen) official doc. After firing this command

`rnv run -p tizen -d -t 192.168.1.235`

no error shows up in the console, everything goes well but the TV stays in White Screen (attaching image below).

[tizen tv image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHgdS.jpg)

The app is working well in the simulator, but unable to run the same on real TV.

Similar GitHub issue: https://github.com/renative-org/renative/issues/925

any help highly appreciated. Thank You!

System :

Renative: @rnv/renative": "0.36.1",
Tizen Studio: version 5.0.0
Windows 10

I've tried all the given steps but the desired result of launching the app on TV is not yet reached.